# Traffic light Simulator Error

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a traffic light simulator in python,it is running proper however after the first run it just ends , I need it to be on a loop ,for example red-yellow-green and then again red-yellow-green and so on..What am i  missing here? I am new to python,if this is a noob question please don't report
Below is my code:

```
import time
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *
tk=Tk()
win=Canvas(tk, width=55, height=200)
win.pack()
#functions
def red(a):
for i in range(a):
    red=win.create_oval(5,5,50,50, fill="red")
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.05)
def redb(a):
for i in range(a):
    red=win.create_oval(5,5,50,50, fill="black")
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.05)
def amber(a):
for i in range(a):
    amber=win.create_oval(5,55,50,100, fill="orange")
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.05)
def amberb(a):
for i in range(a):
    amber=win.create_oval(5,55,50,100, fill="black")
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.05)
def green(a):
for i in range(a):
    green=win.create_oval(5,105,50,150, fill="green")
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.05)
def greenb(a):
for i in range(a):
    green=win.create_oval(5,105,50,150, fill="black")
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.05)
def lights():
red=win.create_oval(5,5,50,50, fill="black")
amber=win.create_oval(5,55,50,100, fill ="black")
green=win.create_oval(5,105,50,150, fill="black")
#end of functions
#calling the functions

lights()
red(30)
redb(1)
amber(10)
amberb(1)
green(30)
greenb(1)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Drawing and redrawing the "lights" every time seems unnecessary. If you maintain references to each light you could simply change its colour using [itemconfig](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a loop over the light changing code:

```
lights()
while True: # use a better termination condition here
    red(30)
    redb(1)
    amber(10)
    amberb(1)
    green(30)
    greenb(1)
```

Please note that:

```
for i in range(a):
    amber=win.create_oval(5,55,50,100, fill="black")
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

it's the same as:

```
amber=win.create_oval(5,55,50,100, fill="black")
tk.update()
time.sleep(0.05 * a)
```

Because the for loop is just repainting the oval and sleeping for 0.05 secs `a` times.

Comment: Thank you,it helped ,however didn't get what is wrong with using the while termination condition?

Comment: `while True` will run indefinitely. Use some user input like pressing a button or a key, or easier, loop over N seconds.

Comment: How about this                                                                                
    import time

   t_end = time.time() + 60 * 15
   while time.time() < t_end:
   lights()
   red(30)
   redb(1)
   amber(10)
   amberb(1)
   green(30)
   greenb(1)